# C# SSL Authentication hangs

Tags: c#, authentication, sockets, ssl

Here is my server code:

```
 public TCPConnection(Socket _socket)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("1");

     SendSync = new object();
     Client = _socket;
     StreamHandle = new SslStream(new NetworkStream(Client, true), false);
     Console.WriteLine("2");

     StreamHandle.BeginAuthenticateAsServer(Module.ServerCertificate, false, SslProtocols.Tls12, false, EndAuthenticate, null);

     //StreamHandle.AuthenticateAsServer(Module.ServerCertificate, false, false);
     Console.WriteLine("3");

     //Offset = 0;
     //HeaderSize = 4;
     //ClientBuffer = new byte[HeaderSize];
     //StreamHandle.BeginRead(ClientBuffer, (int)Offset, (int)HeaderSize, ReadClientData, null);

 }

 private void EndAuthenticate(IAsyncResult ar)
 {
     try
     {
         StreamHandle.EndAuthenticateAsServer(ar);
         Offset = 0;
         HeaderSize = 4;
         ClientBuffer = new byte[HeaderSize];
         StreamHandle.BeginRead(ClientBuffer, (int)Offset, (int)HeaderSize, ReadClientData, null);
     }
     catch
     {
         StreamHandle?.Dispose();
         Client?.Dispose();
     }
 }
```

My client side code:

```
public TCPConnection(string _ip, string _port)
{
    this.IP = _ip;
    this.Port = _port;

    Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
    {
        ReceiveBufferSize = 50 * 1024,
        SendBufferSize = 50 * 1024,
    };



    string ServerIP = _ip;
    int ServerPort = Convert.ToInt32(_port);

    if (IsValidDomainName(ServerIP))
    {
        IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(ServerIP); 

        foreach (IPAddress theaddress in addresslist)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket.Connect(theaddress, ServerPort);
                if (Socket.Connected) break;
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Socket.Connect(ServerIP, ServerPort);
    }
    if (Socket.Connected)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
        IsConnected = true;
        Stream = new SslStream(new NetworkStream(Socket), false, (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true);
        Console.WriteLine("1!");

        //Stream.BeginAuthenticateAsClient("N10XServer", null, SslProtocols.Tls12, false, EndAuthenticate, null);
        Stream.AuthenticateAsClient("ServerName", null, SslProtocols.Tls12, false);




        HeaderSize = 4;
        Buffer = new byte[HeaderSize];
        Offset = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("4");

        //Send(IdSender.SendInfo());
        Interval = 0;
        ActivatePong = false;
        KeepAlive = new Timer(new TimerCallback(KeepAlivePacket), null, new Random().Next(10 * 1000, 15 * 1000), new Random().Next(10 * 1000, 15 * 1000));
        Ping = new Timer(new TimerCallback(Pong), null, 1, 1);

        Console.WriteLine("5");


        Stream.BeginRead(Buffer, (int)Offset, (int)HeaderSize, ReadServertData, null);


    }
    else
    {
        IsConnected = false;
        return;
    }
}
```

My client code works very well on my Windows Machine. It also works well on my Phone using Xamarin. But when I implement it into my c# Maui app it hangs on Stream.AuthenticateAsClient. Sometimes I also receive an exception: IOException:  Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
Im using Xiaomi Redmi Note 5. There's no firewalls enabled.

Do anyone know how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to make this fully `async`, which means moving it out of the constructor into an `async` function